# c# cannot print the document for the second time. vshost32.exe has stopped working error occurs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Program works fine for the first time print. but when i'm going to print the second receipt error occurs.

Screen shot of first error [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8M60.jpg)

I tried (as i foundd on internet)- unchecked enable visual studio hosting process and checked enable unmanaged code dubugging after that now it gives an error like this..

screen shot of second error [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tt6zc.jpg)

Code :

```
private void btnprint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (txtcash.Text == "" || txttpri.Text == "" || txtftot.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Input Cash Price ! ", "Sales", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                }
                else
                {
                    txtbal.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txtcash.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(txtftot.Text)).ToString();

                    printDialog1.ShowDialog();
                    printDocument1.Print();

                    radreta.Enabled = true;
                    radwhol.Enabled = true;
                    radreta.Checked = false;
                    radwhol.Checked = false;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Printing Issue !", "Message");
            }
        }




private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                salesconnection.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmdprint = new OleDbCommand();
                cmdprint.Connection = salesconnection;
                cmdprint.CommandText = "Select * from saletrans";
                OleDbDataReader printreder = cmdprint.ExecuteReader();
                int x = 50;
                int y = 65;
                int width = 800;
                int height = 0;
                StringFormat left = new StringFormat();
                left.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;

                StringFormat center = new StringFormat();
                center.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;


                e.Graphics.DrawString("                       Toyota Motor Corporation Area Store Branch  ", new Font("Georgia", 15, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.DarkRed, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), left);
                y = 85;
                e.Graphics.DrawString("                                              No:56,Kurunegala Road,Katugasthota", new Font("Georgia", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.DarkRed, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), left);
                y = 100;
                e.Graphics.DrawString("                      toyotamotorcorporation@gmail.com / TpNo: 081-2225468/081-2224445", new Font("Georgia", 11, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.DarkRed, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), left);
                y = 138;
                e.Graphics.DrawString("  " + "Product ID" + "             " + "Product Name" + "           " + "Unit/P" + "        " + "Quantity" + "         " + "Sub Total(Rs:)", new Font("Georgia", 13, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.CadetBlue, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), left);
                y = 146;
                e.Graphics.DrawString("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~", new Font("Georgia", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.CadetBlue, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), left);
                x = 110;
                y = 155;
                while (printreder.Read())
                {
                    y = y + 20;
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("" + printreder["ProductID"] + "               " + printreder["ProductName"].ToString(), new Font("Georgia", 13, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), left);
                    y = y + 20;
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("                                                                 " + printreder["Unitprice"] + "           x            " + printreder["Quantity"].ToString() + "                  =   " + printreder["Total"].ToString(), new Font("Georgia", 13, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), left);
                }


                y = y + 25;
                x = 60;
                e.Graphics.DrawString("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~", new Font("Georgia", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.CadetBlue, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), left);

                y = y + 15;
                x = 490;
                e.Graphics.DrawString("Grand Total              " + txtftot.Text, new Font("Georgia", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.DarkRed, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), left);

                y = y + 20;
                e.Graphics.DrawString("Cash                            " + txtcash.Text, new Font("Georgia", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.DarkRed, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), left);

                y = y + 20;
                e.Graphics.DrawString("-------------------------------------", new Font("Georgia", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.DarkRed, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), left);

                y = y + 20;
                e.Graphics.DrawString("Balance                            " + txtbal.Text, new Font("Georgia", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.DarkRed, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), left);

                x = 60;
                y = y + 30;
                e.Graphics.DrawString("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~", new Font("Georgia", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.CadetBlue, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), left);

                y = y + 20;
                e.Graphics.DrawString("Customer Name & ID : " + txtcname.Text +" / "+ cmbcid.Text, new Font("Georgia", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.DarkBlue, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), center);

                y = y + 30;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(frmlog.user.ToString() + "      " + DateTime.Now, new Font("Georgia", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.DarkBlue, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), center);

                y = y + 20;
                e.Graphics.DrawString("** Exchange Possible Within 7 Days **", new Font("Georgia", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.DarkBlue, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), center);

                y = y + 20;
                e.Graphics.DrawString("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~", new Font("Georgia", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.CadetBlue, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), left);

                y = y + 20;
                e.Graphics.DrawString("Software by NKP Developer", new Font("Georgia", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.DarkBlue, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), center);


                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("E:\\NIBM\\C#\\GROUP PROJECT\\graphics\\Billlogo.png");
                Point loc = new Point(300, 15);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, loc);

                printreder.Close();

                salesconnection.Close();

                salesconnection.Open();
                OleDbCommand deleteall = new OleDbCommand();
                deleteall.Connection = salesconnection;
                string del = "delete from saletrans";
                deleteall.CommandText = del;
                deleteall.ExecuteNonQuery();
                salesconnection.Close();


                dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
                dataGridView2.Refresh();
                cmbcid.Enabled = true;
                cmbcid.Text = "";
                txtcname.Text = "";
                txtbal.Text = "";
                txtcash.Text = "";
                txttpri.Text = "0";
                txtftot.Text = "0";
                btnnewbill.Enabled = false;
                btnpurdelete.Enabled = false;
                btncalculate.Enabled = false;
                btnprint.Enabled = false;

                sum = 0;


            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Printing Issue !", "Message");
            }

        }
```

Comment: kindly post your code instead of posting only your error images.

Comment: sry for that. now its updated.